# How can I fix MySQL installing error

Tags: mysql

I was trying to install MySQL and got bump by this error any idea how to fix it ?.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC1oH.png)

Comment: What information about the error is on the log tab?

Comment: @Dave All it' said is "An error occurred trying to add new users to the MySQL database (see log)." so any idea how to fix this please.

Comment: Are you sure the users are not already created? The server seems to be installed and working.